# Api call with localStorage data that comes asynchronously in React

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I need to make API calls with localStorage data that comes only when session validation is completed.
The user logs in, the home screen opens and after a few ms, the localStorage is filled with data.
This data is used to make calls to fill the home sessions.

My current solution was creating a context called "didUpdate" and changing its value whenever the session validation is completed.

Then, in the components I create a state for the localStorage data like this:

`const [userData, setUserData] = useState(localStorage.getItem("userdata"));`

and then, the useEffect hook to set the state again when the didUpdate changes:

`useEffect(() => { setUserData(localStorage.getItem("userdata")); }, [didUpdate]);`

It works fine, but I wonder if there is a better solution.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can set an event listener on the localstorage or you can use a third party library as this one https://usehooks.com/uselocalstorage. There's no better way these days to listen for changes over the localstorage in react.